# How to create two beans with the same class by methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I want to create Clazz, where I can create two Beans with the same class, but with the different configuration.

```
public class Clazz {
//same class : Client, inside has the different configuration
//inicilized by methods
@Bean(name="Bean1")
public Client1 (){}

@Bean(name = "Bean2")
public Clien2t (){}
}
```

Then I want to inject them in other classes

```
public class ClassForInjectBean1{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("Bean1")
@NotNull 
Client client
....
}

public class ClassForInjectBean2{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("Bean2")
@NotNull 
Client client
....
}
```

I have tried this construction in classes ClassForInjectBean1 and ClassForInjectBean2

```
@Resource(name = "Bean2")
@NotNull 
Client client
```

and

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("Bean2")
```

But spring does not understand

Ошибка : 
Parameter 1 of constructor in ClassForInjectBean1 required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - Bean1: defined by method 'Client1' in class path resource...
    - Bean2: defined by method ''Client2' in class path resource...
Why I can't do that?

I know that there is this way https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation, but I don't to create many classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html).

> Indicates that a class declares one or more @Bean methods and may be
>   processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and
>   service requests for those beans at runtime

I provided some example for you.

```
@Configuration
public class Cfg {

    @Bean("client1")
    public Client client1() {
        return new Client("client1");
    }

    @Bean("client2")
    public Client client2() {
        return new Client("client2");
    }
}
```

```
public class Client {
    private String name;

    public Client(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Client{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class InjectionTest {

    @Component
    public class ClassForInjectBean1 {
        private final Client client;

        public ClassForInjectBean1(@Qualifier("client1") Client client) {
            this.client = client;
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void testInit() {
            System.out.println(client.toString());
        }
    }

    @Component
    public class ClassForInjectBean2 {
        private final Client client;

        public ClassForInjectBean2(@Qualifier("client2") Client client) {
            this.client = client;
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void testInit() {
            System.out.println(client.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

---

Output would be:

```
Client{name='client2'}
Client{name='client1'}
```