# How to use same kotlin class to make 2 connections using configurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Currently, My project consists of a config class having lateinit var and a connection class which uses this config to make connection to the DB. Here is dummy code of what it looks like for a single connection and it works fine-

Config.kt-

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="db")
@Scope("singleton")
open class Config {
    lateinit var schema: String
    lateinit var account: String
}
```

Connection.kt-

```
@Configuration
open class Connection(private val config: Config) {
    fun makeConn()
    fun fetch()
}
```

application.properties-

```
db.schema=ABC
db.account=myAcc
```

main.kt-

```
open class dataFetch(
        private val config: Config,
        private val connection: Connection
) {
// Do something with config.schema
// Do something with connection.fetch()
}
```

Now I want to make 2 connection with the same config class values and connection class. Only the connection properties need to be changed. What is a good way of doing this? I have made 2 copies of both classes and made it work but it's ugly and repetitive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create two beans with the same class by methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279150/how-to-create-two-beans-with-the-same-class-by-methods)